# Event on rename worksheet tab not triggered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to listen to "worksheet tab renamed" events? It will be relevant for us to know when this event occurs as we display this information in our own UI addon.

The `onEdit()` function is not triggering on sheet renaming.

Comment: You can refer to spreadsheet tabs by ID.  So, if a user renames a tab, but your code is finding the correct tab by ID, then the name is immaterial.  I think you need to get all the sheet tabs, then loop through them to find the right one.   I don't think you can get a sheet tab directly by ID.  Which should be available, but don't think it is.  There is an `onChange()` event which you didn't mention trying.  I'm not sure if detects a tab rename, but I'd check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEdit` trigger fires when the content of some cell is changed. All other changes must be detected by `onChange` trigger. The corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) has changeType equal to `'OTHER'`  when the change is renaming a sheet. As an example, set onChange trigger to this function ([can be done programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange))

```
function change(e) {
   if (e.changeType == 'OTHER') {
     // do something
   } 
}
```

The event object does not say what was renamed and to what (and `OTHER` may be some other type of change, too). So, you will need to have the list of sheet names stored in script properties, and when the event fires, compare it to the new  one.