# How to pass event object to .onChange() trigger in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to add a trigger to my Google Sheet so that a certain function is run (say for example an alert is to ui) when any sheets are renamed.

I found the following post that explains a workaround
[Event on rename worksheet tab not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311685/event-on-rename-worksheet-tab-not-triggered)
but I'm not sure if this will actually work because it is not what document this listener is supposed to listen to.

From my previous experience writing successful even triggers for Google Forms we have to use a trigger builder like the following example. Now if I want to pass the `event` to `myFunction` in the following code how do I do it?

```
let currentSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forSpreadsheet(currentSs)
.onChange()
.create();

function myFunction() {
 if event.changeType === 'Other' {
  //do this
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "myFunction").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onChange().create();
  }
}

function myFunction(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'OTHER') {
    //do this
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried this eliminating the first if() and .filter() part. Can you please elaborate why we need to filter out the triggers to only retain those that have "myFunction" handlers? @Cooper

Comment: We want to make  sure that we don't create more than one trigger for a function.